# symfony2 php engine templating render all files in a folder

Tags: php, symfony, rendering, symfony-3.1

I am using the standalone **symfony form** with **php templating**.
I setup all , validated all forms normaly but when I try to render a form I got the following error :

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException: No 
 block "form_widget_simple" found while rendering the form
```

I figured out why this : I must define all the form_* block to do this.
In the framework they defined all this stuff in a directory **...Resources/view/Form** I copied this file in my project and starting to extend them with that

```
<?php $view->render("...../symfony/Resources/views/Form/form_widget_simple.html.php",
                  array("form"=>$form)) 
?>
```

My page started to render some input but

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException: No block "widget_attributes" found while rendering the form.
```

So I am wondering how to render them all by default before trying to render my templates 
thanks.

**UPDATE**
here is my template simply call the **form_widget_simple**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Standalone Form Component</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <?php $view->get("form")->block($form,"form_widget_simple"); ?>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the controller that call the template

```
<?php
   echo $templating->render('agent/test.php', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
  ));
 ?>
```

the full **error**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException: No block "form_widget_simple" found while rendering the form.
in /mnt/1070E7B870E7A2A8/wamp/www/ingrmc/application/vendor/symfony/form/FormRenderer.php:100 
Stack trace: #0 /mnt/1070E7B870E7A2A8/wamp/www/ingrmc/application/vendor/symfony/templating/Helper/FormHelper.php(213):
Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer->renderBlock(Object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormView), 'form_widget_sim...', Array)
 #1 /mnt/1070E7B870E7A2A8/wamp/www/ingrmc/application/vue/agent/test.html.php(8): 
Symfony\Component\Templating\Helper\FormHelper->block(Object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormView), 'form_widget_sim...') 
#2 /mnt/1070E7B870E7A2A8/wamp/www/ingrmc/application/vendor/symfony/templating/PhpEngine.php(152): require('/mnt/1070E7B870...') 
#3 /mnt/1070E7B870E7A2A8/wamp/www/ingrmc/application/vendor/symfony/templating/PhpEngine.php(80): Symfony\Component\Templating\PhpEngine->evaluate() 
#4 /mnt/1070E7B870E7A2A8/wamp/www/ingrmc/application/_RESSOURCES/php/commun.php(85): Symfony\Co in /mnt/1070E7B870E7A2A8/wamp/www/ingrmc/application/vendor/symfony/form/FormRenderer.php on line 100
```

Comment: pleas add more debug information. Show your template. Which functions are used in template? Your template is inherited from something?

Comment: thks i added the debug information and the template in the original question